# Google+ client that takes up less space?

Tags: google-plus

Has anyone tried a Google+ client that takes up less space than the standard client from Google Inc.? My phone gets full very quickly and right now the Google+ client is one of the largest installed apps I've got. Any suggestions?

The most useful feature of the client compared to using the browser version is that I can do "Share" from any other app, usually Google Reader, directly to Google+ without having to copy+paste the URL I want to share.

EDIT: This is on an HTC ChaCha (Status) which has a pretty tight memory space.

Comment: Have you tried moving it to the SD card? No disadvantages unless you want to use the widget.

Comment: @avilella: unfortunately, it seems Google+ API currently only provides read-only access to data (https://developers.google.com/+/api/); this means that it is unlikely that anyone would be able to write an alternative Google+ client without reverse-engineering Google+'s web interface or official client (which is not officially supported, therefore might be unstable and/or even a TOS violation). As is typical for Google, I'm positive they have plans to release a write API in the near future; but currently a full-fledged alternate client seems unlikely.

Comment: @LieRyan Google generally doesn't really care if someone uses their undocumented APIs e.g. the dictionary and weather ones are working without any issues and some are working on one for the music one too.

Answer (score 5):

The mobile web version of the Google+ can be accessed from the browser. It provides all the basic features, although since it's just a web app there is no integration with the OS (no notification, etc).

Size? 0 kb.

Comment: It doesn't let me do "Share to Google+" from another app, unless there is a magical way of doing "Share to bookmark"...

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19397/share-to-bookmark

Comment: The size is not truly 0kb, as the browser will cache the data accessed. You would have to regularly clear the browser cache, in the same way you could clear the app's cache. Though presumably the browser cache is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched though the Android Market and it dosen't look like there are any other app's which can do that.

But if you need space you can install a custom ROM on your phone and make an external partition on your sd card.

Then you can get 1 GB ekstra space for apps etc.

But since i don't know which phone you have, i can't point you to a specific guide.

But i would do that or you can try App2SD from the market, which can move some of the apps to your sd card :)

Answer (score 0):

Google+ api does not support many features at the moment. Or i should say the API is readonly at the moment.

Due to this limitation there are hardly any apps for Google+, till that time either stick to google+ app, or the web app.

Since HTC Cha Cha is using Android 2.3 (Ginger Bread), you should be able to move Google+ to the SD card. (Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> Downloaded (tab) -> Select Google+ -> Move to SD card)

or the alternate solution is install Apps2SD (lightweight app), and use it to l

Comment: did u manage to find some solution?