# Share to bookmark

Tags: bookmarks, share-menu

Is there any way of having a "Bookmark" as part of the items in the "Share" options that show when one clicks "Share" on a given app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an app [Bookmark Home](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.lagoscript.bookmarkhome) which adds *Add bookmark* to the share list. If you send a bookmark to it, it will be stored in the apps own storage, but there is an export option to save all of them in the Browser bookmarks.